# Eclipse crash after opening .xml file

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-layout, eclipse-3.5

i am starting with android development
i have created some sample application but 
when i am opening .xml file resides in res/layout/main.xml
after that my eclipse crash and close.

i even try "open with android layout editor" which also crashes eclipse.

i am not getting why this problem occur.

my os is ubantu 9.04
and using eclipse Galileo

**EDIT:**

i am getting following error in my eclipse log file. what dose this means???

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2011-04-29 16:56:16.476
!MESSAGE loadAndParseRClass failed to find class com.saltriver.gui.R
!STACK 0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:465)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMonitor.loadAndParseRClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMonitor.fileChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.GlobalProjectMonitor$DeltaVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:48)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.GlobalProjectMonitor$1.resourceChanged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$2.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1809)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$NotifyJob.run(NotificationManager.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: I had this happen a few times when the xml was read as a single line. If I broke it up in to many lines, eclipse had no problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"crash" is not very specific. Look into the file `.metadata/.log` in your workspace to see if Eclipse wrote an error message before it died.

If that doesn't help, start Eclipse from a console with `-debug -console -consoleLog`.

**[EDIT]** The error means that you're using Java X to run Eclipse but a plugin needs Java Y (where Y > X).

the usual case is that you run Eclipse with Java 5 and you have a plugin which needs Java 6. Unfortunately, the error message is useless: It doesn't tell you which class is the problem, from which JAR it came, which version it has and which versions are supported - The code has all the information but some smart guy decided that you don't need that. Pity.

So try to get the latest version of Java to run the IDE.

**This is independent of the Java version which you use to build and run your projects!! It's just the VM which Eclipse uses to load its plugins. For VMs used in projects, see the Eclipse preferences.**

Comment: hey this is working now it just required jdk1.6 as java home path see http://javamesamples.blogspot.com/2011/04/setting-javahome-in-ubuntu.html for setting JAVA_HOME Setting in Ubantu.

Answer (score 2):

Close 'Eclipse'

Go to your `Eclipse` folder open `eclipse.ini` file in any text editor.

after the line which says `openFile` add following two lines.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javaw.exe
```

(This folder path may vary according to your java installation directory).

save and close.

Open eclipse and tadaaaa!!! you can open `xml` files again. :)